# Cant upload shaded jar to nexus

Tags: maven, nexus

I'm trying to deploy a maven project to our Nexus using Gitlab-Ci but the pipeline always fails when trying to upload the shaded-jar created by the maven-shade-plugin. Any Ideas why this is so?

The pipeline Error:

```
[INFO] Uploading to pp-snapshots: https://nexus.myplayplanet.net/repository/myplayplanet-snapshots/net/myplayplanet/MyPlayPlanet-Core/1.14.0-SNAPSHOT/MyPlayPlanet-Core-1.14.0-20190929.002150-7-shaded.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  02:53 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-09-29T00:21:51Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project MyPlayPlanet-Core: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact net.myplayplanet:MyPlayPlanet-Core:jar:shaded:1.14.0-20190929.002150-7 from/to pp-snapshots (https://nexus.myplayplanet.net/repository/myplayplanet-snapshots/): Connection reset by peer (Write failed) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

The shade-plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
        <filters>
            <filter>
                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </filter>
        </filters>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I had been using the wrong maven image.
I just used maven:latest but when I changed it to maven:3.6.2-jdk-8, it works again.

Answer (score 0):

The error is:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) 
  on project MyPlayPlanet-Core: 

Failed to deploy artifacts: 

Could not transfer artifact net.myplayplanet:MyPlayPlanet-Core:jar:shaded:1.14.0-20190929.002150-7 
from/to pp-snapshots (https://nexus.myplayplanet.net/repository/myplayplanet-snapshots/)

Connection reset by peer (Write failed)
```

Check the size of your snapshot artifact, there could be a size limit issue.

Check also your JDK version used locally, as in [this issue](https://github.com/kt3k/coveralls-gradle-plugin/issues/85#issuecomment-425668577)

> Disabling the TLS 1.3 protocol with:
>
> ```
> -Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
> ```